# Positioning elements on resizable parent image

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

I'm reworking my travel photography site in order to make it work better on different devices/resolutions. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and their responsive options and the majority is going okay but I've now run into a snag.

On the existing site I have a map showing all locations I've been to ([you can see it here](http://importedlight.com/map.php)).

My question is, on the new site, the map is going to resize and if that happens the pins indicating the locations are going to be in the wrong place. I presume I need to somehow check the width/height of the map and then somehow dynamically change the positioning of the map markers but I'm having trouble finding out how to do this. JQuery I guess (which isn't a strength of mine).

Done some searches but this seems a little specific and I haven't found anything. Grateful if anyone's got any ideas.

Comment: It's not a big issue. Say you resized (See the jquery resize event if this is dynamic) the map with a factor `X` then the coordinates of the existing points need to be multiplied with `X` and repositioned. Hide the pins if they fall outside the rectangle. Give it a try and then post more specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Set css of **star** `position:absoulte` and with `top:` `left` `right` `bottom` attribute set position

Comment: Milind - That's how to place the markers, yes. And its what I did in the old version linked ot above where the map size was fixed. But that won't work on the new version where the map changes size.